# return all rows in json format

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Good day. I want to return all the rows in my database table and return it in json format, but my current code will only return a single row. I tried to 
 changed $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
 to fetch_all(); sad to say it returns an error.

Hope you can help me guys.

db_func.php

```
public function  getBrnchInfo($br_code){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT branches.BranchesID as 'br_id', branches.BranchesDesc as 'br_desc', branches.Address as 'br_add', branches.Manager as 'br_manager', branches.ACRONYM as 'br_accronym', semaphor.semTransactionDate as 'br_trans_date'
                    FROM branches
                    LEFT JOIN semaphor ON SemBR_CODE = BranchesID
                    WHERE BranchesID= ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $br_code);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $userData = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $userData;
    }else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

branch.php

```
$user = $db->getBrnchInfo($br_code);
//var_dump($user);
if ($user != null) {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"]["ar_class"] = $arclass;
    $response["user"]["loan_class"] = $loanclass;
    $response["user"]["accnt_receivable"] = $accintreceivable;
    $response["user"]["br_code"] = $user["br_id"];
    $response["user"]["br_desc"] = $user["br_desc"];
    $response["user"]["br_address"] = $user["br_add"];
    $response["user"]["br_manager"] = $user["br_manager"];
    $response["user"]["br_accronym"] = $user["br_accronym"];
    $response["user"]["br_trans_date"] = $user["br_trans_date"];
   // echo json_encode($response, true);
}
else {
    echo "Branch Code ". $br_code. " does not exist in " . "<strong>Table Branch</strong>";
}
```

Comment: json_encode()...

Comment: what do you mean sir @Enstage?

Comment: Use that function to convert an array to a JSON string.

Comment: its already in json format sir. but my problem is it will only return a single row in a table. I want to return all the rows in the table and convert to json

Comment: It is not already in JSON.

Comment: it iss sir.. if I uncomment the // echo json_encode($response, true);

Comment: [`fetch_assoc();`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) will always returns **one** row, if you want more rows you'll have to loop over the result and if it does not work give us the error you get.